# How to get content of all ajax requests in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Task: change the domain URL to another in all ajax requests on the front of the site - CMS Wordpress. I see that all AJAX requests go through wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, but how do I process the output then? Where in Wordpress the output is generated. I need a generic option so that any AJAX request coming from the front will go through the domain replacement function.

Comment: While it might be possible, there's an issue: some of these AJAX requests might be using [nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/nonces/) to verify that the request is coming from the site and not from another domain. Changing the URL so requests are sent to an external site might break some stuff. Just my two cents.

Comment: I need not to change the request address. Every AJAX request has a response. I need to change the domain in the received answer.

Comment: Well, technically you could try and change these URLs on the backend using PHP but for that I'd image you'll need to check all of the functions that hook into [wp_ajax_*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) and hope that they provide a way to filter the response before returning it to the script making the AJAX calls. If they don't then you may need to edit these functions by hand. Alternatively, you could just update your JS code and change the URL there before using the response on the front-end.

Comment: The thing is, I'm looking for a universal solution. I need to change all links in order to give them to CDN. Is there some common callback for ajax functions? After all, one file is used to process requests.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what you're trying to achieve now but that might be quite tricky to pull off (and possibly impractical too). Anyways, have a look at [wp_ajax_](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) and [wp_ajax_nopriv_](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/) and get ready to dig deep into WP's source code. Good luck!